# How can validate image dimension and size for 3 target platforms each with different image dimensions but same size in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am working on a feature for an image uploader for different platforms with different recommended image dimensions.
For example
platform 1 - dimension 920 x 300
platform 2 -210 x 200
platform 3 - 790 x 270
when the select file button is clicked an image is preview if the image dimensions are not the same as the recommended for a specific platform it should be flagged also the size shouldn't be more that 1mb on all platforms. I am having issue modifying the recommended dimension validation.
this is my code

```js
 data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      rules: [
      images => !image || !images.some(image => image.size > 2048)  || 'Image size should be less than 1 MB!',
     ],
     
     
     async selectedFile() {
      const MAX_SIZE = 100000;
      const MAX_WIDTH = 500;
      const MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
      this.imageError = '';
      
      let file = this.$refs.myFile.files[0];
      
      if(!file || file.type.indexOf('image/') !== 0) return;
      this.image.size = file.size;
      if(this.image.size > MAX_SIZE) {
        this.imageError = `The image size (${this.image.size}) is too much (max is ${MAX_SIZE}).`;
        return;
      }
      
      let reader = new FileReader();
      
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = evt => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => {
          this.image.width = img.width;
          this.image.height = img.height;
          console.log(this.image);
          if(this.image.width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            this.imageError = `The image width (${this.image.width}) is too much (max is ${MAX_WIDTH}).`;
            return;
          }
          if(this.image.height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            this.imageError = `The image height (${this.image.height}) is too much (max is ${MAX_HEIGHT}).`;
            return;
          }         
        }
        img.src = evt.target.result;
      }
      reader.onerror = evt => {
        console.error(evt);
      }
      
    },
    async onFileChange(e) {
      let self = this
      this.loadingImage = true
      let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
      if (files && files[0]) {
        self.formData.TypeofDocument = files[0].name
          .split('.')
          .pop()
          .toLowerCase()

        const file = files[0]

        await CMS.uploadImageToCloud(file, fileUrl => {
          this.formData.LinkToDocument = fileUrl
          this.loadingImage = false
        })
      }
    },
```

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submit" style="padding: 10px;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>{{ $t('Platforms') }}</label>
            <select class="form-control" v- 
               model="formData.PlatformTypeID">
              <option
                v-for="(platform, index) in platformTypes"
                :key="index"
                :value="platform.ID"
                >{{ platform.Name }}</option
              >
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>{{ $t('Select Image') }}</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
                <img
                 :rules="rules"
                  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg,image/png"
                  v-if="formData.LinkToDocument"
                  :src="formData.LinkToDocument"
                  class="img-responsive"
                  height="100"
                />
                <img
                  src="~/static/img/loading.gif"
                  height="100"
                  v-if="!formData.LinkToDocument && loadingImage"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <input
              type="file"
              v-on:change="onFileChange"
              id="fileInput"
              style="display: none"
            />
            <button
              type="reset"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              align="center"
              :disabled="loadingImage"
              @click="selectFile"
            >
              {{ $t('Choose File') }}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="row marginTop">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
              <button
                v-if="!isLoading"
                type="submit"
                id="saveBtn"
                class="btn btn-success text_white btn-block text-white btn-md btn-responsive"
                tabindex="7"
              >
                {{ $t('Save') }}
              </button>
              <button
                v-if="isLoading"
                class="btn disabled btn-success text_white btn-block text-white btn-md btn-responsive"
                tabindex="7"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner fa-1x"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
              <router-link
                to=""
                class= `btn btn-default btn-block btn-md btn-responsive`
                >{{ $t('Cancel') }}</router-link
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tegv6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and works :)

```html
<v-img
                        alt="image"
                        :src="image_url"
                        contain
                      ></v-img>
```